# Learning Unity 3d with eclips for beginner

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I am new in unity 3d.I have a little knowledge about it.I heard that unity 3d is use for making game.It also can be used for making android game.So that's why i need to learn it from the beginning.Do you have any good link,documents,videos for learning it with android?Please....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can go on http://www.unity3dstudent.com/ to learn the basics.

And to do Andoid stuff you should just check that the fonctions you use are in
http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/Components/index.html
Uncheck all plateform exept Android.